# How to count users who visited more than X times in a period

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elasticsearch-aggregation, cardinality

I'm trying to count active users for the service. We consider a user active if he did more than X actions in a span of a particular time period. Count will do fine, the list of user ids is not necessary. 
I couldn't find the suitable query in Elasticsearch, not just Graphana. Terms aggregation can't do that because it only return top 10 buckets. Composite and cardinality aggregation don't allow minimum document count. 
Value count and top hits don't have the necessary data and/or filters. Regular and extended stats work only with numeric fields.
What am I missing?

Comment: The `terms` aggregation can return more than 10 buckets if desired

Comment: @val I need the count, not the data itself. can I do that with terms?

Comment: @Val didn't think so

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer from a person who contributes to Elasticsearch. Basically he says [there's no built-in query to do this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32452#issuecomment-414645200)

P.S. It's my understanding that Elasticsearch is not the solution to this type of queries. Redis and/or Druid might be a better fit